# Schengen visa form: sponsor and applicant both

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, sweden

I am going from India to Sweden for an internship. The flights and accommodation costs are provided by the sponsor. But I have to bear other living expenses. So in section 33 of the Schengen visa form, can I tick both the left and right sides as the sponsorship is partial?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use both portions of section 33 to indicate how your stay in Sweden would be provided for financially.

[image]